# how to search documents by field property in Elasticsearch using java？

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

I want to search docs which `type=0`,how to build search query using java?

Comment: People will not be able to answer your question the way it is. Please go through the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your query using QueryBuilder in java.

Here's a sample code for the same:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
TermQueryBuilder termQuery = new TermQueryBuilder("tasks.type", 0);
boolQuery.must(termQuery);
```

And then simply query using NativeSearchQueryBuilder, as shown in snippet below:

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices("YOUR_INDEX_NAME")
            .withTypes("EVENT_TYPE_NAME").withQuery(boolQuery)
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 60));

SearchQuery searchQuery = queryBuilder.build();
```

Above snippet will generate a search query to find the type field with value 0.

You can use ElasticSearchTemplate to query elastic Search as shown below:

```
ElasticSearchTemplate  template = new ElasticSearchTemplate();
.queryForList(searchQuery, YOUR_CLASS.class).forEach(System.err::println);
```

So your final java code will look something like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
TermQueryBuilder termQuery = new TermQueryBuilder("tasks.type", 0);
boolQuery.must(termQuery);
NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withIndices("YOUR_INDEX_NAME")
        .withTypes("EVENT_TYPE_NAME").withQuery(boolQuery)
        .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 60));

SearchQuery searchQuery = queryBuilder.build();
ElasticSearchTemplate  template = new ElasticSearchTemplate();
template.queryForList(searchQuery, YOUR_CLASS.class).forEach(System.err::println);
```